# AppEngine - Writes are limited to 1 per second

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm looking into using the AppEngine DataStore for a database system, but I'm confused by this quote in the documentation:

"**This allows queries on a single guestbook to be strongly consistent, but also limits changes to the guestbook to 1 write per second (the supported limit for entity groups).**"

Source: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/hr/overview.html

Now does that mean that if I have my data model setup like:

```
class Guestbook(db.model)
    guestbook_name = string property
    datecreated = date property

class Message(db.model)
    guestbookOwner = guestbook reference
    messageText = string property
    datecreated = date property
```

No matter what data I commit with a message, ie:

```
mess = Message()
mess.guestbookOwner = guestbook
mess.put()
```

It will still be limited to 1 write per second? - I wouldn't mind if it were limited like this, if it were based on the guestbook reference and the new message.

Help please!

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey, nope, having a reference to another entity and belonging to the same entity group as another entity are two independent things.

Entities belong to the same entity group only if you explicitly supply a `parent` argument when you [instantiate](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Entity_Groups_and_Ancestor_Paths) either of them.  Modeling an entity class so that it has a reference to another entity doesn't mean you're required to give it a `parent` when you construct it and therefore doesn't imply that it has to belong to an entity group with other entities.

The writes-per-second limit with High Replication applies to entity groups, so if you don't `parent` your entities to one another, each entity will be its own solo entity group.  In that case, the writes-per-second limit will apply to each entity, not across entities.

Comment: So if the parent for my message was ie: "blue", would all messages written to the entitygroup have the 1 seocnd limit, similarly, I could then set parent to "red" and the limits be set on that too. Maybe I need to learn more about entitygroups/parents

Comment: As you have it in your original post, your messages do not have a parent.  They are "root entities," are all in different entity groups, and the 1 write per second limit is set on each individual message alone.  You could write many, many different messages per second.  If you were to continually change a specific message, you would be limited to one write per second per message.  If you grouped several messages in a single entity group, your writes to any of those messages would be combined under the 1 write per second limit.