# GAE Entity group / data modeling for consistency and performance

Tags: python, entity-framework, google-app-engine, data-structures, google-cloud-datastore

As a continuation of [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828768/gae-implications-of-ndb-hierarchy-and-entity-groups/20830077?noredirect=1#comment31270354_20830077), this is a bit of a capstone-style question to solidify my understanding of [gae-datastore](/questions/tagged/gae-datastore) and get some critiques on my data modeling decisions.  I'll be modifying he Jukebox example created by @Jimmy Kane to better reflect my real world case.

In the original setup,

---

imagine that you have a jukebox with queues per room let's say. And people are queueing songs to each queue of each jukebox.

```
J=Jukebox, Q=queue, S=Song

   Jukebox       
   / |   \        
  Q1 Q2   Q3     
 / |  \   | \
S1 S2  S3 S4 S5
```

---

First, fill out the Song model as such:

```
Song(ndb.Model):
    user_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
    status = ndb.StringProperty()
    datetime_added = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

My modification is to add a `User` that can CUD songs to any queue. In the frontend, users will visit a UI to see their songs in each of the queues, and make changes. In the backend, the application needs to know which songs are in each queue, play the right song off each queue and remove songs from queues once played.

In order for a User to be able to see its songs in queue I'm presuming each User would be a root entity and would need to store a list of Song keys

```
User(ndb.Model):
    song_keys = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Song', repeated=True)
```

Then, to retrieve the user's songs, the application would (presuming user_id is known)

```
user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
songs = ndb.get_multi(user.song_keys)
```

And, since `get`s are strongly consistent, the user would always see non-stale data

Then, when queue 1 is finished playing a song, the application could do something like:

```
current_song.status = "inactive"
current_song.put()
query=Song.query(ancestor=ndb.Key('Jukebox', '1', 'Queue', '1')).filter(Song.status=="active").order(Song.datetime_added)
next_song = query.get()
```

Am I right in thinking that the ancestor query ensures consistent representation of the preceding deactivation of the current song as well as any CUD from the Users?

The final step would be to update the User's song_keys list in a transaction

```
user = current_song.user_key.get()
user.song_keys.remove(current_song.key)
user.put()
```

**Summary and some pros/cons**

- The consistency seems to be doing the right things in the rightplaces
  if my understanding is right?
- Should I be concerned about contention on the `Jukebox` entity group?

  - I wouldn't expect it to be a high throughput type of use case but my real-life scenario needs to scale with the number of users and there are probably a similar number of `queue`s as there are `user`s, maybe 2x - 5x more `user`s than `queue`s. If the whole group is limited to 1 write / sec and lots of users as well as each queue could be creating and updating songs, this could be a bottleneck
  - One solution could be to do away with the `Jukebox` root entity and have each `Queue` be its own root entity
- `User.song_keys` could be long-ish, say 100 `song.key`s. [This article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling) advised "to avoid storing overly large lists of keys in a ListProperty". What's the concern here? Is this a db concept and moot with ndb's way of handling lists with the `repeated=True` property option?

Opinions on this approach or critiques on things I'm fundamentally misunderstanding?

- Presumably, I could also alternatively, kind of just symmetrically flip
  the data models and have entity groups that look like `User` ->
  `Song` and store `song_keys` lists in the `Queue` model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should reconsider how important is strong consistency for your use case. From what I can see it is not critical that all this entities have strong consistency. In my opinion, eventual consistency will work just fine. Most of the time you will see up to date data and only sometimes (read: really really rarely) you will see some stale data. Think about how critical is that you always get up to date data vs how much it penalizes your application. Entities that need strong consistency are not stored in the most efficient way in terms of number of reads per second.

Also if you look at the document [Structuring Data for Strong Consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency), you will see that it mentions that you can't have more then 1 write per second when using that approach.

Also having entity groups effects data locality as per [AppEngine Model Class docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass).

If you also read the famous Google's doc on [Google Spanner](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://research.google.com/archive/spanner-osdi2012.pdf&ei=KLXIUquTK6a5iAfT04G4DA&usg=AFQjCNGsDSbI6WcU-7rcr_OGZks3DDHWMg&sig2=3NoDiUbLkBC1lXNtTOGr7A&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aGc), section 2 you will see how they deal with entities which have same parent key. Essentially, they are put closer together. I assume Google might be using similar approach with AppEngine Datastore. At some point, according to [this](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/05/16/google_spanner_datastore/) source Google might use Spanner for AppEngine Datastore in the future.

Another point, there is no cheaper of faster get then get by key. Having said this, if you can somehow avoid querying this could reduct the cost of running you application. Assuming that you're developing a web application you can store your song keys in a JSON/text object and then use Prospective Search API to get up to date results. This approach requires a bit more work and requires you to embrace eventual consistency model as the data might be slightly out of date by the time it reaches the client. Depending on your use case (this does not apply a small application and small user base obviously) the savings might out-weight the cost. When I say the cost I mean the fact that data might be slightly out of date.

In my experience, strong consistency is not a requirement for a large number of applications. The number of applications that can live with slightly stale data seems to outnumber the applications that cannot. Take YouTube for example, I don't really mind if I don't see all the videos immediately (as there's such a large number that I can't even know if I see all of them or not). When you design something like this, first ask yourself question, is it really necessary to provide up to date data or a bit stale data is good enough? Can the user even tell the difference? Up to date data is much more expensive then a little bit stale.

Comment: Do you think my answer, i.e. mostly ignoring entity groups and relying on lists of keys with gets instead, addresses the performance concerns? This should allow me to write more than 1/sec, no? And I would expet the autocaching will be triggered via memcache in a large % of requests? Also, why do you think eventual consistency will work just fine? My real situation is similar in structure to the Jukebox but not a Jukebox - eventual consistency is probably fine but wouldn't strong consistency provide a better experience and possibly simpler coding?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this "And I would expet the autocaching will be triggered via memcache in a large % of requests?". What is the behavior that you're expecting?

Comment: Also you can use ancestors without using ancestor queries on blind writes. @diddleboo just mentioning.

Comment: @Jimmy Kane, can you clarify - I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @diddleboo i think the 1s/write does not apply in not using a query or transaction. But I am not sure. Or maybe the 1s/write is something new.

Comment: @diddleboo I was wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089485/appengine-writes-are-limited-to-1-per-second

Comment: @JimmyKane that's what I thought indeed and the main reason for structuring with the list of keys instead. No entity groups = avoid the 1 write / second limitation while using gets still achieves strong consistency and memcache will keep read performance very high.

Comment: @markovuksanovic For the cases I'm dealing with, there's a bit of an argument for strong consistency. It would be _nice_ for users to see an accurate list of songs just after changes to the queues but it's not strictly imperative and could be achieved elsewhere in the application rather than strong consistency at the DB level. In my application, it's fairly important that songs are picked accurately - my actual application is more like an auction and bids must be cleared accurately on a schedule.

Comment: Nice and complete answer

Answer (score 2):

I've decided to take another approach, which is to rely on lists of song_keys at the Queues in addition to the Users.  This way, I have strong consistency when dealing with Users and with Queues without needing to deal with the performance/consistency tradeoff that comes with entity groups. As a positive byproduct, `get`ting `keys` leverages ndb autocaching so I anticipate a performance boost with enhanced code simplicity.

Still welcome any critiques...

UDPATE: A little more detail regarding autocaching. [NDB automatically manages caching](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache) via memcache and an in-context cache. For my purposes, I'm mostly interested in the automatic memcache. By using predominantly `get` requests in favor of queries, NDB will check memcache first before reading from the datastore for all of those reads. I anticipate most requests to actually be fulfilled out of memcache rather than the datastore.  I understand that I could manage all of that memcache activity myself and most likely in a way that would work decently with a query-focused approach so perhaps some wouldn't consider that a great rationale for the design decision.  But the impact on code simplicity is pretty nice.

Comment: Storing the keys in a list of keys that grows big doesn't sound good. In my humble opinion if you are going to store a lot.

Comment: Try to keep your entities easily retrievable by keys. Apart from memcache (doing gets on the key after constructing it programmatically after instead of querying for it), it will help for building better abstractions. In the case of the queue and songs also one thing we didn't mention is how much the writes per queue can be. What I mean is that the more the queues the more the isolation of the 1s/write limit.